# Want to put two 'li' in the same line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make legend for JQPlot charts. I am making the legend with un-ordered list.
I have a list and creating li using the response from the server. The ul is..

```
<ul class='tab' id='list1'></ul>
```

JS code for li creation:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    $('#list1').append($('<li>', {
        'style': "width: 15px; background:#987654;'"
    }));
    $('#list1').append($('<li>Helloooooooooooooooooo | 09</li>'));
}
});
```

CSS code for li alignment

```
.tab {
list-style: none outside none;
width: 120px; // list width must be 120px
height: 300px; // list height must be 300px
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: auto;
}
.tab li {
border: solid 1px blue;
text-align: center;
font-size: 12px;
float: left;
display: inline;
height: 15px;
width: 200px;
}
```

Fiddle page:
http://jsfiddle.net/ankitlamba009/W9LXf/

Since, I am not good in CSS so I am not getting my li in same line.
Please help...

Comment: You are giving a max width, so it goes to the next line...

Comment: Max width of what?
If it is li then I gave scroll-bar for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need twice the count of `<li>` elements? here is my suggestion:

**demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/W9LXf/6/

**javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        var li = $('<li>Helloooooooooooooooooo | 09</li>');
        var color = $('<span>').addClass('color').css({
           backgroundColor: "#987654"
        });
        li.prepend( color );
        $('#list1').append( li );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First, give your ul `100%` width and `display:inline-block;`....in 120px wide `ul`, how do you expect `200px` li to be present???

[**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/f3k6n2xr/2/)

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

ul.tab {
  border: 1px solid red;
  list-style: none outside none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul.tab > li {
  border: solid 1px blue;
  float: left;
  max-width: 70px;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    $('#list1').append($('<li>Helloooooooooooooooooo | 09</li>'));
  }
});
```

Comment: I have only 150px wide area for this list.

Comment: give me a minute then :)

Comment: @AnkitLamba Assuming you want to put 2 "li"s on same line, sum of "li" widths should be less than "ul"s width

Comment: @Imray : thanks for informing.... updated with some added changes...hope it helps :)